# separate meta keys on implode

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php echo strip_tags(stripslashes($row = implode(['meta_keys']))) ?>
```

all it shows is "meta_keys" as display, and not the info from the database.

I'm trying to get each key individually linked on an `<a href="">` tag.

I know I need to array, but any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this in comments in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22826930/1491895

Comment: You don't have the correct arguments to `implode`. And I think you mean `explode`. Don't you understand the difference?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$row['meta_keys']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$meta_keys = explode(',', $row['meta_keys']);
foreach ($meta_keys as $key) {
    echo strip_tags($key) . ' ';
}
```